# Category Id coming same all the time in different category page magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Hello I know this is simple question but I don't get any solution in here. So I am going to ask.

I am using magento 1.9, In category page I have widget on left sidebar to display current category's all product. When I change the category, for example if I am on saree's page then if I go to Dress page then in left sidebar the old category that is saree's product are displaying.

I think category id is coming from cache that is not changing it is remain same.

I write following line to fetch the current category.

```
 $_category = Mage::registry('current_category');
 $catid = $_category->getId();
```

But the category id coming which we have open first time.

**Q.** How to resolved I have search the similar question but I don't any appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
```